# JPQL Many to Many conditional query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

I have two entities: News and Tag with Many to Many relation. News has a Calendar field. I have an array of longs with some Tag ids and a Calendar. I want to get all Newses which have at least one Tag from specified in ids array and only those which have newer Calendar then the one I possess. What is the best way to achive it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change tagIds type to List<Long>, which you pass as parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combined answers of JB Nizet and Mikko Maunu:

```
SELECT DISTINCT n FROM News n INNER JOIN n.tags t
WHERE t.id IN (:tagIds) AND n.timestamp > :timestamp
```

It requires List to be passed, array won't do.

Answer (score 4):

```
select n from News n inner join n.tags tag
where tag.id in (:tagIds)
and n.theCalendarField > :calendarParam
```

Comment: I assume in is a typo and it should be id. Even though, I get following exception: Encountered array-valued parameter binding, but was expecting [java.lang.Long]

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. The exception you get is, I think, cause by a Hibernate bug. Replace `in :tagIds` by `in (:tagIds)`.

Comment: Still sth is wrong. Oh god I'm so stupid, I passed Strings instead of longs. I'll check it in a minute.

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate a bit more. I can't read your screen. What exception do you get? What does it do wrong? Error messages are intended to be read, and provide helpful information. "sth is wrong" is not helpful at all.

Comment: Sorry for being inspecific. It is the same error it was before, check my edit.

Comment: Show us the code used to bind parameters and execute the query.

Answer (score 3):

What you do not show, is type of `tagIds`. According message in expection, its is array. Because you are comparing against Long, type of parameter should be one of the following: long, Long or `List<Long>`.

Comment: Thanks mate, that did it. However if I have e.g. 7 Tags in my list, I get list of Newses with 7 identical entites. I've added DISTINCT and it did the trick but don't know why it works that way.